# Parsing ExpressionEngine Error Template with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, expressionengine

I'm trying to add Ajax to my ExpressionEngine registration form with the [jQuery Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/). Most of the form errors are handled with [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) and returned in JSON, and I've had no major problems parsing those. The only error that isn't handled by Profile:Edit is when someone tries to re-register with an email address that is still "pending". For that, I get the [standard EE error template](https://gist.github.com/4033821) in HTML.

What I'd like to do is set up a jQuery `$.each()` loop and output the error list item(s). But when I try to parse the HTML I get weird data in the console. Even a really simple jQuery function doesn't work like I expect. For example, with this code, I expect to get back the content of the `#content` div:

```
$('.myForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data){
        var theContent = data.find('#content');
        console.log(theContent);
    }
});
```

But I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object
<!-- Full HTML of Error Template -->
has no method 'find'
```

The same thing happens if I use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`.

If I wrap `data` in selector syntax, like this:

```
$('.myForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data){
        var theContent = $(data).find('#content');
        console.log(theContent);
    }
});
```

I get this in the console:

```
[prevObject: e.fn.e.init[9], context: undefined, selector: "#content"]
    context: undefined
    length: 0
    prevObject: e.fn.e.init[9]
        0: #text
        1: <title>
        2: #text
        3: <meta>
        4: #text
        5: <style>
        6: #text
        7: <div>
        8: #text
        length: 9
    __proto__: Object[0]
    selector: "#content"
    __proto__: Object[0]
```

Which is not what I expected, nor do I really know what to do with it.

Setting the `dataType` as 'html' doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any thoughts? This thing has aged me by years, it's so damn frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data.find('#content');
```

Won't work because data is not a jQuery object. What does the response coming back look like? If you do a console.log(data) upon success, what do you get?

Comment: `console.log(data)` returns [the contents of the full EE error template](https://gist.github.com/4033821).

Comment: I actually experienced some weirdness when doing an AJAX request recently.

What if you do something like:

var $data = $('<div id="dummy">' + data + '</div>');

And then do $data.find('#content'). Does that select the element correctly?

Comment: Your gist appears to have the html source of the error page returns twice. Is that your result?

Comment: @TrevorDavis Doing that gives me [this](https://gist.github.com/4035449). Slightly more useful but still just as mystifying.

Comment: @AllInOne Ah, sorry about that. No, the error page is only returned once. I've fixed the gist to reflect that.

Comment: Weird, the log isn't what I expected. But, can you do $data.find('#content ul').html() and get your list of errors?

Comment: @TrevorDavis That does indeed work, but man, what a messed-up way of going about it! Why does EE vex me so?

Comment: @TrevorDavis you should update your answer with the solution.    kgrote you should accept it! :-)